# PhpStorm: after update to 2022.3.1 npm watcher failed

Tags: npm, phpstorm, webstorm, chokidar, npm-watch

After PhpStorm update to 2022.3.1 the npm watcher fails.

If I **start from terminal inside PhpStorm** (version 2022.3.1), the following error is thrown:

```
...
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/fs/watchers:244:19)
    at Object.watch (node:fs:2301:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:119:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:166:15)
    at NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:331:14)
    at NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:559:19)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:608:16)
    at async /var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:445:21
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:641:10)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:636:18)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:445:21
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src',
  filename: '/var/www/html/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src'
}
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.15.0 -> 9.3.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.3.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.3.0 to update!
npm notice
```

This error **only** appears if **PhpStorm is open**.

**Current workaround:**

- Close PhpStorm.
- Start the watcher request from *system terminal* (runs without errors).
- Open PhpStorm to work on dev code.

**Questions:**

- Where can I check my last PhpStorm update, is there a log file available?
- Why PhpStorm calls more files to watch than the system terminal *and* is it so?
- Is there a configuration for this issue in PhpStorm?

**UPDATE #1**
Run PhpStorm one day later and use its terminal to start the watcher, the watcher works normally. This behavior has been observed before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"Where can I check my last PhpStorm update, is there a log file available?"* What exactly you want to see? Overall log -- `Help | Show Log in XXX` an dit will open your system file browser and point to a `idea.log` file. To download previous version: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/other.html If you use ToolBox App to install your IDE -- check for that there.

Comment: @LazyOne thx for your answer, i looking for the date/s of  updated phpstorm

Comment: Every time you launch the IDE, it writes into that log the boot process (where configs are, what plugins are enabled etc). The session starts with an entry that has `-- IDE STARTED --` line (surrounded by 40 or so more `-` on every side. It also includes what version is that (e.g. `... #c.i.i.AppStarter - IDE: PhpStorm (build #PS-223.8214.64, ...`)

Comment: did you try increasing the limit of inotify watchers on your system (https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached)?

Comment: @lena Yes, i can do this. But this is not a solution, just a workaround...